# Can a 14-year-old US citizen living abroad with non-US citizen parents come to US for high school study if both parents have no objection?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, legal, education

Can a 14-year-old US citizen living abroad with non-US citizen parents come to US for high school study if both parents have no objection (and no US visa to accompany the child to the US)?

1. Parents wish to send me to boarding school.
2. Parents do not child to enter foster care.
3. There is no assigned legal guardian on US soil, since parents have no US visa.

Please let me know if this can be worked out.

Comment: It makes a big difference whether it is a public or private school. Public schools usually have rules to prevent students from enrolling unless at least one parent or guardian lives in the school district. They don't want to spend the money to educate the student unless the parent or guardian pays taxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no legal obstacle to this.

In order to attend boarding school in the US, you need to first [find a boarding school](https://www.boardingschools.com/find-a-school.aspx) and [apply for admission](https://www.privateschoolreview.com/blog/admissions-to-private-school-a-z), which can be a very long process so you better start early.

If you have lived outside the US for most of your life, you may be considered an [international student](https://www.boardingschoolreview.com/blog/international-students-guide-to-boarding-schools) for most school purposes, such as requiring an English exam before admission, even though luckily you won't need any visa or immmigration papers.

Once you select some specific schools you're interested in, you can also call them to get more information and answers to any questions you have about what they require.